# Using Node, how do I handle Data/End/Error events with Connect?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been working on learning Node, and created a web server that works, something like:

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var data = "";

    req.on("data", function (d) {
        data += d;
    });

    req.on("end", function () {
        // process code
        var html = ...
        res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
        res.end(html);
    });

    req.on("error", function () {
        // handle error
    });
});

server.listen(3000); // port
console.log("127.0.0.1:" + server.address().port); // localhost:port
```

Branching out to expand my knowledge, I'm using Connect and some other modules:

```
var http = require("http");

var bodyParser = require("body-parser"); // parse request body - req.body
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser"); // parse cookie header - req.cookies
var session = require("express-session"); // user session - req.session (uses cookies)

var connect = require("connect");
var app = connect();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({ secret: "shhh, it's a secret", resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var data = "";
    req.on("data", function (d) {data += d;});
    req.on("end", function () {...});
    req.on("error", function () {...});
});

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(3000); // port
console.log("127.0.0.1:" + server.address().port); // localhost:port
```

Essentially, I am using the previous function from http.createServer() in the final app.use().

Again, works fine ... EXCEPT ... for POST requests I do from a submit button.

In that case, the data/end/error events never fire.

I have found that if I just ignore the data/end/error events, and just basically code the logic of the end event in my app.use(), things work fine, and the POST data comes through.

I'm assuming the lack of a data event still works because any .js or .css files are small enough to not need multiple chunks, and for images I am using fs.createReadStream.

I have no error event, but then I have yet to encounter a situation where that ever actually fires.

I plan to dive deeper into Connect, and Express, later on, but not now (unless I need to).
Want to learn Node at this point.

So, I guess, my question is,
when working with Connect (app.use) how do I properly deal with data/end/error events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is a complete answer, but I moved and modified this from the req.on("end") chunk of code and put it in a separate app.use() just before the final one.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var contentType;
    switch (path.extname(url.parse(req.url, true, true).pathname)) {
        case ".css":
            contentType = "text/css";
            break;
        case ".gif":
            contentType = "image/gif";
            break;
        case ".ico":
            contentType = "image/x-icon";
        case ".jpeg":
        case ".jpg":
            contentType = "image/jpg";
            break;
        case ".js":
            contentType = "text/javascript";
            break;
        case ".png":
            contentType = "image/png";
            break;
        default:
            next();
            return;
    }

    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": contentType });
    fs.createReadStream(__dirname + req.url).pipe(res); // async, kind of
});
```

Pretty much handles all the non-HTML files so the data event for those doesn't worry me so much anymore.